# When you observed an quantum measurement, do you know the measurement result?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, measurements, measurement-problem

Consider a quantum system A with state $|a\rangle$. Scientist B use an instrument to measure A. The state collapse and obtained an result.

Suppose there is an observer C, treating B and its instrument as an quantum system, is in state $|b\rangle$.What C knows about is there is an interaction between A and B,  C also knows about the evolution operator U of composite system A and B. If C try to compute reduced density matrix of A, is it going to be a mixed state or a pure state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This scenario is known as the [Wigner's friend](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend) thought experiment, and entire books have been dedicated to it. Like many thought experiments in quantum mechanics, the answer is controversial and depends on your interpretation of quantum mechanics. In the Copenhagen interpretation, $A$ is in a pure state; in the many-worlds interpretation, it's in a ("improper") mixed state.

In general, the answer depends on where you place the [Heisenberg cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_cut). Depending on the interpretation of quantum mechanics, the Heisenberg cut either (a) occurs at an objective and universal scale, (b) is a subjective quantity that occurs at different scales for different observers, or (c) is purely an illusion that doesn't "actually exist" at all for any observer.

Comment: There is no issue with this in the ensemble interpretation of QM. See https://arxiv.org/abs/1910.10131